# Append text or values from another page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a newbie in programming, could you help me figure this out.

`index.html`

```
<button id="press">Click here</button>

<div id="show_image">
</div>
<br>
<div id="appended_area"></div>
```

script of `index.html`

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#press').click(function(){

      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "next.html",
          success: function(response){
          $("#show_image").html(response);
          }
        });

    });
});
```

next.html

```
<button id="btn" value="Hello">CLICK TO APPEND</button>
```

QUESTION:
Is it possible to append text or values, real-time, coming from next.html and append it to the div id="appended_area" of index.html when I click the button coming from next.html in this scenario?

NOTE:

only index.html will be used.

next.html is used using ajax.

Comment: I don't think so.

First of all, if next.html is used using AJAX, then how are you planning to use the button

Comment: @ShivamShah, That is really my problem! :)

Comment: Why do you want the button, Is their some specific thing you are doing with it

Comment: I have different navigation tabs. When I click a tab, I display pictures in a div. What I did was, I use ajax to display the pictures in that div. But my problem is, how can I append the names of the pictures clicked on the main page. Hope you can give me some bit of advice @ShivamShah.

Comment: Explain some more. What i get is - You have tabs, which on clicking load some images using AJAX. Now what is the main page, where are the names of those pictures and in which page are the tabs located

Comment: the main page is the index.html where the tabs are located. I just want to display the names of the picture when clicked on a different div. Each picture has a unique name that I want to display.

Comment: @ShivamShah, thanks for your time. I think it is not feasible. Maybe I should try different approach in this matter.. Thanks.

Comment: what is your next.html page loading. You can receive both the image as well as the picture name from your AJAX request

Comment: @ShivamShah, Right! The image and name will come from next.html.. The image will be shown using ajax. The name of the image will be appended to the div of index.html when clicked.

Comment: Now what i dont get is what the button is for in next.html

Comment: @ShivamShah, the button is the image itself. The picture is clickable. Once clicked, the name of the image/picture will append to the page.

Comment: Instead of having a button, just have the image with data-name attribute set to its name. On loading the image using AJAX, add an onClick listener to the image, which will just take the name from the target's data-name attribute and display it.

Comment: @ShivamShah, But can I append it to the index.html? Can I use the data-name attribute from next.html and use it in my index.html?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49321/discussion-between-shivam-shah-and-ritz-de-guzman)

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this, but it starts to get messy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#press').click(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "next.html",
      success: function(response){
        $("#show_image").html(response);

        // jquery should be able to find the button element after it has been added.

        $("#btn").click(function(){
           $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "append.html",
           success : function(data){
             $("#append_area").html(data);
           }
           }); 
        }
      }
    });

});
});
```